# SSO Spring Boot and keycloak

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, keycloak

I would like to do the following:

1. if a user enters a restricted area of my spring secured spring boot
   web application he/she should enter the e-mail address and based on
   the mail domain he/she should be redirected to a specific keycloak
   SSO.
2. if the login was successful keycloak should return to a specific
   endpoint in my application where I manually log-in the user with
   some details send by keycloak.

I redirect the user to the keycloak login using this URL:
http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/XXXXX/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=YYYYY&response_mode=fragment&response_type=token&login=true&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/keycloakResponse

This brings me the login page of keycloak and also a return call to http://localhost:8888/keycloakResponse with the token (as far as I can read it in the response).

Response from keycloak:
http://localhost:8888/keycloakResponse#session_state=XXXXXXXXXXX&access_token=YYYYYYYY.ZZZZZZZZZZZ.AAAAAAAAAA&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=900

My question now is how can I access & verify this information in the servlet to manually log-in the user?

I cannot find any way to access this information.